# Cannot access certain website

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, browser, youtube

to make it simple : **i cannot connect to youtube.com and instagram.com on my laptop**, all other site that i tried to connect is successful, except those two. On chrome, it said:

This site can’t be reached www.youtube.com took too long to respond.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

On Edge it said:

There was a temporary DNS error. Try refreshing the page.
Error Code: INET_E_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND

These are my tracert to youtube.com

```
C:\Users\Lenovo>tracert youtube.com

Tracing route to youtube.com [216.58.221.78]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     2 ms     2 ms     3 ms  192.168.1.1
  2    48 ms    74 ms    53 ms  110.232.86.161
  3    42 ms    17 ms    18 ms  43.229.255.49
  4    75 ms   104 ms    30 ms  43.229.255.33
  5    48 ms    43 ms    80 ms  124-195-60-121.resources.indosat.com [124.195.60.121]
  6    56 ms   129 ms    47 ms  jdtr1-pkm.ge-2-0-0.pkm.jgw01.medan.indosat.com [202.93.34.101]
  7    58 ms    44 ms    44 ms  jgw1-pkm.so-3-1-0.eqx.jnode1.singapore.indosat.com [202.93.41.13]
  8    94 ms    46 ms    43 ms  114-4-19-101.resources.indosat.com [114.4.19.101]
  9    91 ms    74 ms    41 ms  114-0-78-204.resources.indosat.com [114.0.78.204]
 10   205 ms    71 ms    45 ms  74.125.32.36
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12    72 ms    46 ms    56 ms  108.170.237.232
 13    88 ms    33 ms    25 ms  108.170.254.227
 14    61 ms    60 ms    39 ms  216.239.49.74
 15    60 ms   197 ms    32 ms  216.239.57.39
 16   142 ms   134 ms   177 ms  108.170.240.225
 17    77 ms   152 ms    38 ms  108.170.233.65
 18    69 ms   198 ms    52 ms  sin10s01-in-f14.1e100.net [216.58.221.78]

Trace complete.
```

i have tried :

-Browsing youtube from mobile using the same wifi connection (successful)

-Browsing youtube from laptop using mobile tethering (unsuccessful)

(Which from both i conclude it's problem is with my laptop)

-Try ipconfig/release/renew

i'm open to suggestions, Thanks

Comment: Start with the DNS: run `nslookup` from the command line and ask server `8.8.8.8` for the address of youtube.com. Then traceroute it to see if your "normal" name resolutiojn is valid.

Comment: > youtube.com 8.8.8.8
Server:  [8.8.8.8]
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    youtube.com
Addresses:  2404:6800:4003:80c::200e
          216.58.221.78

Comment: the end address is the same ip

Comment: The IP address `216.58.221.78` is correct, so not a DNS problem. Maybe a firewall problem with your ISP? Try using a VPN.

Comment: Next use `nc`  and `openssl s_client` to make sure nothing in the way is blocking HTTP[s] (each time saying just 'GET / HTTP /1.0')

Comment: i can use tor browser to access youtube just fine, but its not a way out tho

Comment: @EugenRieck sorry to ask, but how to do that, what is nc, i did a few googling about openssl and found it's a linux thing, do i need to go there?

Comment: Both nc and openssl can be downloaded for Windows - they come from the UNIX world but have long been ported.

Comment: using the openssl i got this

OpenSSL> s_client -connect www.youtube.com:443
9724:error:0200274C:system library:connect:reason(1868):crypto\bio\b_sock2.c:110:
9724:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:crypto\bio\b_sock2.c:111:
connect:errno=0
error in s_client

Comment: using the nc, i got nothing in return, just blank

Answer (score -1):

I found it, and don't blame me for not searching it in the first place, its the **hosts** file.
I don't know if anything changed that caused the problem, but i had used it for about a years or two and no problem at all in those times, the code is too long to include here, but inside i included the code from

> https://someonewhocares.org/hosts/

and some code from reddit unblocking site through hosts

so yeah, thanks to Eugen Rieck for the time, u r cool dude, also i still want to know what further step in case anyone else got screwed up too :D